RDS PostgreSQL - Change encryption type from aws_s3 extension
I have installed aws_s3 extension in Aurora PostgreSQL to write/read table data in S3 bucket.
I am able to create S3 objects by exporting DB query result set and able to read from it from the DB using the aws_s3 in-built functions with General Purpose S3 buckets.
But I am not able to do it with Express One Zone buckets which is a Directory bucket.
The reason being a different type of Server Side Encryption.
1. General Purpose S3 bucket
I executed the below function that comes with aws_s3 extension which exports/imports successfully for General purpose S3 bucket.
SELECT rows_uploaded FROM aws_s3.query_export_to_s3 (query=>'select * from table_test', s3_info=>aws_commons.create_s3_uri('gen-purpose-bucket-1--usw1-az6--x-s3','/tables/table_test', 'us-west-1'),  options=>'FORMAT text');
The above function executes successfully and exports data to S3 bucket.
2. Directory S3 bucket (Express One Zone)
I execute the same function for Directory bucket and I get the error as below.
SELECT rows_uploaded FROM aws_s3.query_export_to_s3 (query=>'select * from table_test', s3_info=>aws_commons.create_s3_uri('express-one-zone-bucket-1--usw1-az6--x-s3','/tables/table_test', 'us-west-1'),  options=>'FORMAT text') ;
Error :
ERROR: Amazon S3 client returned 'Unable to parse ExceptionName: InvalidRequest Message: Session was created with ServerSideEncryption as AES256 but request header specifies SSE-KMS.'.could not upload to Amazon S3

The function aws_s3.query_export_to_s3 has a parameter kms_key to which I tried passing the value AES256 still it fails with the same error.
However, I am able to create the object in Express One Zone bucket when I run the below command from CloudShell.
aws s3api put-object --bucket express-one-zone-bucket-1--usw1-az6--x-s3  --key test --server-side-encryption AES256

Any help on this is much appreciated.
